# ScrollView Scrollbartrack visibility

Tags: android, scrollview

[image]

[image]

I want to remove the shadow(scrollbartrack) shown below scrollbarthumb.
But unable to do it. I tried to set `android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@null"`

Please ignore the black part.

Comment: have u tried android:scrollbars="none" ? in your scrollbar tag

Comment: i want the scroll bar but not the track which is appearing as shadow

Comment: edited the answer

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using XML or code.

In XML:

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/yourScroll"
    android:scrollbars="none" <!-- add this -->
    >
```

or in your code:

```
yourScrollView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
yourScrollView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

---

**Edit**

You have changed the question with your new image , for that task add drawable image as your requirement to `android:scrollbarThumbVertical`

```
<ScrollView
        android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/line"   <--like this-->
        android:id="@+id/my_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp">
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="400dp">
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

**Note** : My drawble image contain transparent area(in left and right sides) ,thats why its bit right from the edge

[image]